# How can I create a Scala XMLEventReader that reads from stdin?

Tags: xml, scala

I want to be able to pipe an XML file into a program and read it with an `XMLEventReader`. The only constructor I can find for `XMLEventReader` takes a `Source` as a parameter, but `scala.io.StdIn` is not a `Source`and I can't find any way to turn it into a `Source`. Can it be done, and, if so, how?

Comment: `XMLEventReader` is deprecated: https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/pull/199 . I would not recommend it using it at all, for anything.

Comment: That's interesting - but the link doesn't say what I should use instead...

Comment: I'm not an expert on what alternatives exist, but https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/package-summary.html seems like a popular choice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `java.lang.System.in` as an `InputStream` or [`scala.Console.in`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/Console$.html) as a `BufferedReader`. Prefer the latter because it can be easily modified in tests (using `Console.withIn`).

```
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource

val source = new StreamSource(Console.in)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a StreamSource, which you can create from an InputStream or a Reader.